# OpenLayers | CloudPopUp

Tags: javascript, jsf, api

Estou tentando fazer uma popup usando o OpenLayers (mais especificamente usando Ol4JSF) mas a parte de adicionar a *popup* uso o jscript direto, e a *popup* sai toda bugada. Qual o motivo?
[image: imagem da Popup]

Código utilizado:

```
<m:script>
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-47.89460,-22.00710).transform(
new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
);

var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup", 
        lonLat, null,
        'Texto', null,
        true
            );

        map.setCenter(lonLat, 18);
        map.addPopup(popup);  </m:script>
```

Comment: cara, possivelmente é CSS. Eu chutaria alguma regra da sua página interferindo com o popup.

Comment: A Então, consegui Resolver, vou postar a solução, e não era CSS xD

Answer (score 1):

Consegui Solucionar o problema, foi adicionando o codigo Javascript fora da tag  do OL4JSF :D, peguei de um exemplo do componente e adaptei, o estranho que se tem aquela tag, era pra todo o jscript em relação ao mapa ir la, mas anyway

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta aí do lado esquerdo.